# Запрос метки "[google-apps-script]"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, создание-метки

Позвольте обосновать свое пожелание. На данный момент мы имеем

```
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+
| google            | google-maps-api   | google-chrome      | google-play      |
| google-maps       | google-app-engine | google-maps-api-v2 | google-analytics |
| google-gson       | google-api        | google-docs        | google-translate |
| google-calendar   | google-docs-api   | google-drive       | google-plus      |
| google-adwords    | google+           | google-spreadsheet | google-dart      |
| google-speach-api | google-keep       | googleauth         | google-webmaster |
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Ни одна из меток не описывает действительности о Google Apps Script, а именно

> Google Apps Script is a scripting language based on JavaScript. [Источник](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)

Далее по меткам, которые уже есть:

- [google-docs-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-docs-api) - это API Документов, не более, у Таблиц есть свой API.
- [google-docs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-docs), [google-spreadsheet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) - взрывной тэг для программиста, что он вообще означает?
- [google-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api) - как ни странно, Google Apps Script это не API.

Прошу удовлетворить запрос на добавление метки **[google-apps-script](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)**.

Простите, первый раз в театре - совершенно забыл добавить посты для примера, которые необходимо отметить этой меткой:

- [Google Apps Script сохранить письмо в черновиках](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/250926/google-apps-script-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)
- [Скрипт для автозамены символов в spreadsheets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/408648/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-spreadsheets/415393#415393)

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в тело вопроса ссылку на вопрос, который следует отметить данной меткой.

Comment: не нужно javascript метку удалять при добавлении google-apps-script. Последнее более точно, но не страшно если избыточность будет (на  часть вопросов по google-apps-script наверняка можно ответить, основываясь на знании javascript). Что означает [google-docs](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-docs/info) и [google-spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-spreadsheet/info) -- смысл их использования такой же как у windows, linux меток у вопросов по python -- дополнительный контекст, иногда это важно.

Comment: Понимаю, хорошо, конечно.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov Мы можете использовать `[tag:tag-name]`, чтобы ссылаться на теги на основном сайте.

Answer (score 5):

Как ни странно, но метка [google-docs-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-docs-api), уже существует. Более того, первый из приведенных вами вопросов был ей отмечен с самого начала. Второй поправил.

**Обновление**

Прозевал, поправил. [google-apps-script](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)

Comment: Необходим [google-apps-script]

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.